# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I am getting this error when i start tomcat

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at      org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1301)
at    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1232)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3666)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4258)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
```

i have already put the servlet.jar in classpath and tomcat_home/commons/lib folder

please can any one suggest what to do.

Answer (score 11):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter

This particular exception can occur when you have got a copy of the `servlet.jar` which originated from an ancient Servlet 2.2 container or older and that file got precedence in classloading over Tomcat's own libraries. The `Filter` class was namely [introduced](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) in Servlet 2.3.

---

> *i have already put the servlet.jar in classpath and tomcat_home/commons/lib folder*

You should not do that. **Remove** all servletcontainer-specific libraries from your `/WEB-INF/lib`, the "classpath" and the Tomcat's `/common/lib` folders.

The Tomcat servletcontainer *already* ships with the right APIs in its own `/lib` folder. You should not have any copy in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`, nor elsewhere in the classpath, also not the ones from a completely different servletcontainer.

This common beginner's mistake of attempting to download/copy random servletcontainer specific libraries is commonly caused by the inability to compile servlet classes by javac or in the IDE. When using javac, you need to reference Tomcat's `/lib` in the `-cp` argument. When using an IDE, you need to reference Tomcat as *Targeted runtime* in project's properties.

#### See also:

- [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)

Comment: after removing the copy of servlet.jar and start the tomcat iam geting the error SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy

Comment: That's a different problem. Your initial problem is solved. You're now a step closer to a successful deploy. This exception just means that the given class (or, more concretely, the JAR containing the given class) is missing in the runtime classpath. You'd need to drop it in `/WEB-INF/lib`. Ask a new question if you stucks, this is completely unrelated to the current question.

Answer (score 3):

add this to your pom.xml, replace the version with any latest stable version. search for spring-web in mvnrepository.com and get the latest version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unable to find the jar version of servlet jar that was causing issue, I explicitly added correct version of jar to Tomcat classpath :

[image]

This jar resides in `%TOMCAT_HOME%/lib`

Note : ensure servlet-api jar appears first.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you [have a servlet.jar somewhere that you shouldn't](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Class_Not_Found#Q2). Make sure the only servlet.jar you have is in commons/lib, per the FAQ.

Comment: after removing the copy of servlet.jar and start the tomcat iam geting the error SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy